# How to draw a point from WFS server?

Tags: openlayers, wfs

I am using this script in openlayers 3:

```
  var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
      var url = 'http://www.sujb.cz/gis/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
          'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=abmerit:mleko&' +
          'outputFormat=json&format_options=callback:loadFeatures' +
          '&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
      $.ajax({url: url, dataType: 'jsonp', jsonp: true});
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
      maxZoom: 19
    }))
  });
  window.loadFeatures = function(response) {
    vectorSource.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response));
  };

 var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
                    source: vectorSource,
                    name: 'layer9',
                    visible: false,
                    style: vectorstyle
                    });
```

from XML file like this:

```
<gml:null>unknown</gml:null>
</gml:boundedBy>
  <gml:featureMember>
    <abmerit:mleko fid="mleko.fid--36e9d52e_1533e824588_-735d">
    <abmerit:id_zppr>1000</abmerit:id_zppr>
    <abmerit:odbermisto>Bohunice - kravín</abmerit:odbermisto>
    <abmerit:monit_polozka>mléko kravské - surové</abmerit:monit_polozka>
    <abmerit:datum_zac>2015-01-14T07:55:00</abmerit:datum_zac>
    <abmerit:datum_kon>2015-12-30T08:00:00</abmerit:datum_kon>
    <abmerit:the_geom>
    <gml:Point srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#900913">
      <gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">1601158.32985051,6310367.83231571</gml:coordinates>
    </gml:Point>
  </abmerit:the_geom>
  <abmerit:hodnota_cs137>None</abmerit:hodnota_cs137>
  <abmerit:monit_polozka_en>raw cows´milk</abmerit:monit_polozka_en>
  </abmerit:mleko>
  </gml:featureMember>
```

and I'm still not able to draw at least points at those coordinates.. only in debug mode in browser i can see, that its connected to xml file right..

Comment: Don't know the syntax but `visible: false` makes me think that you may set data as invisible.